# Mongodb how to move specific object from array to another array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have the following collection:

```
{  
  "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"),
  "first":[  
    {  
      "shape":"square",
      "color":"blue"
    },
    {  
      "shape":"circle",
      "color":"red"
    }
  ],
  "second": []
}
```

What I want to do is, first find a specific object inside the `first` array and move that to `second` field

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192")}, {$pull: {first: {color: "red"}}, $push: {// that specific object to second array}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in a single operation. You can do this instead, though:

```
MyModel.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"), "first.color": "red" }, 'first.$', function (err, doc) {
    MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"), {
        $pull: { first: { color: "red" } },
        $push: { second: doc.first[0] }
    }, function (err, docs) {  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using cursors.

```
db.getCollection('test')
    .find({_id: ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192")})
    .forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.second = doc.first.filter(function(x) { return x.color === "blue"});
        doc.first = doc.first.filter(function(x) { return x.color !== "blue" });
        db.getCollection('test').save(doc)
    }
)
```

Replace "blue" with your chosen item.

This will however work for your example but will remove any previous items in second.

If you just want to append it this should work.

```
db.getCollection('test')
    .find({_id: ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192")})
    .forEach(function(doc) {
         doc.second = doc.second.concat((doc.first.filter((x) => x.color === "green")));
         doc.first = doc.first.filter(function(x) { return x.color !== "green" });
         db.getCollection('test').save(doc)
      }
)
```